# Timber /towebp - some thumbnails not generating properly (half grey)

Tags: timber

I am using wordpress/woocommerce Timber theme. While uploading images to new product, wordpress generates thumbnails. After saving new product and opening it, Timber generates Timber's thumbnails + webp images - 110 jpg/webp thumbnails for one image because there are different sizes for different resolutions.
One random size webp file is always not fully rendered, a part of it is grey. I have no idea why.